# AES Encryption in Java differs from PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption

I've been doing much searching but can't find an adequate explanation for why this:

```
public class encryption_test {

    private static final String text_encoding = "UTF-8";

    private byte [] byte_array (String input) throws Exception {
        return input.getBytes (text_encoding);
    }// byte_array;

    private byte [] encrypt (String text) throws Exception {
        Cipher cypher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec (byte_array ("12345678123456781234567812345678"), "AES");
        cypher.init (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec (byte_array ("1234567812345678")));
        return cypher.doFinal (byte_array (text));
    }// encrypt;

    public String doit () throws Exception {
        byte [] etext = encrypt ("this is a plain string.");
        return new String (Base64.getEncoder ().encode (etext));        
    }// doit;

}// encryption_test;
```

in Java, yields:

```
dAza6vYiYzJ9W/i4zPHVfvA8UUyw8Sq1g2YjuLt3EjI=
```

Whereas:

```
base64_encode (mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "12345678123456781234567812345678", "This is a plain string.", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "1234567812345678"))
```

in PHP yields:

```
G+tdEOfQTtVCQGxW3N5uzkqN207OyfIPxS6zf2xrKKY=
```

According to everything I've read in the forums, they should both return the same thing. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The strings you're encoding are different. Hint: Capital `T`. It works fine after you fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test strings are different. In Java, you put "this is a plain string.". In PHP, you put "This is a plain string.". Mind the capital 'T'.

Please adjust and try again.

Comment: Yep. That's it. I should have seen it (thus, the benefit of another set of eyes). Thanks.